# Define a route with constraints(it should contains a string) in app.routes.ts in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have to navigate to a component while my url contains '.vpf'.How can i define route for this app.routes.ts

```
   {path:':section',component:SectionBasedListingComponent},
```

It will navigate while I am giving url like http://localhost:4200/anystring.

Similarly I need to navigate while my string contains .vpf .How can i achieve this

can anyone pls help me

Thanks

Comment: share more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use guards for that, check if your string exist and redirect to a new route where you have your new component:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { CanActivate,ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from 
    '@angular/router';

 import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

 @Injectable()
 export class CanActivateRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

 constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
  boolean {
   if (state.url.indexOf('.vpf') !== -1) {
      this.router.navigate(['/yourNewRoute']);
    }
    return true;
  }
 }



{ path:':section',component:SectionBasedListingComponent , canActivate: [CanActivateRouteGuard ]},
```

Comment: thanks,It doesn't hit my authguard service.I am getting  "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '2018/01/25092736/Bus-tariff-hike-protest-Pudukottai.vpf" error.how can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Guards

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public router: Router) {}

 //check for parameter using ActivatedRoute or else

  //Navigate to this.router.navigate(['required path']);
}
```

Check how its done in AuthGurads

```
{ path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```